# partition all unallocated space Mac Mojave

Tags: partition

How do I create a partition out of unallocated space on Mac OS Mojave/APFS? diskutil apfs list in Terminal indicates I have 137.8gb unallocated, but in Disk Utility I can only add a partition up to 68.5gb. I want to make a larger partition. I only have one APFS container that is the same size as the physical disk.

Comment: Can I assume you do no longer need an answer to this question, since you found an answer to the following newer question you posted?: [Boot Camp Assistant removal successful, still can't reinstall](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363108/boot-camp-assistant-removal-successful-still-cant-reinstall)

Comment: After restarting, the other solution no longer worked. Also, I continued to have the same problem in Disk Utility.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the disk layout in Disk Utility