# Boot Camp Assistant removal successful, still can't reinstall

Tags: bootcamp, windows, mojave

I installed Windows 10 via Boot Camp Assistant with no problems yesterday, but needed to uninstall to make the partition larger. I uninstalled it also using Boot Camp Assistant and received no error message. It was successful and Windows was removed. I now want to reinstall, however BCA cannot find the space. I only have one APFS container which contains all of my space and Terminal displays plenty of unallocated space.

I have been searching for four hours and I've encountered a lot of people with problems who didn't use BCA or got an error using it, but I don't know what to do when BCA was successful.

I am on a mid-2012 MBP running Mojave. I understand there are some differences in older and newer Macs when using Boot Camp.

I know I can clean install Mojave and restore from Time Machine before I used Boot Camp the first time, but I would rather avoid it and also I worry about using BCA again, when I had a problem even when it encountered no errors. I want to install Windows again.

diskutil list:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            111.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: It would help if you could include the output from the command `diskutil list`. Also, how much space do you want to allocate to Windows?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was able to follow the steps in this answer and it worked. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354105/extand-main-apfs-partition-on-macos-mojave-10-14-3

Comment: When I put in those commands an hour ago, BCA recognized the extra space. I restarted and ran a new backup before reinstalling Windows, and now I am having the same problem where it is not recognizing the free space, same as before. Editing to add diskutil list. I want to allocate 100GB of 256 to Windows.

Comment: repeating `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` now yields `Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size`

Comment: Have tried removing any time machine snapshots? Try using Mint's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301463/macos-10-13-windows-10-installation-with-boot-camp/347783#347783).